# How do I look at SQL Agent Job without starting SQL Agent?

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I have just set up a new SQL Server instance on a new server and moved our application to use the new server. So I've had to turn SQL Agent off on the old server - turning it on would start the scheduler and start sending out emails and running things that shouldn't be run any more.

However, I need to take a close look at a SQL Agent Job on the old server, and ideally reverse-engineer the code to recreate it so I can modify it and apply it to the new server.

How do I generate the code for that Job on the old server without turning SQL Agent on?
Thanks

Comment: Disconnect it from the network and turn the agent back on and then examine the jobs and plans and whatever else you need. Perhaps disable all the jobs after you start the agent so it doesn't do anything.

Comment: `exec sp_help_jobstep` maybe?

Comment: SMor: thanks for the suggestion, disconnecting it from the network might be tricky - I work remotely, and disabling all the jobs would take too long. But thanks for the suggestions. I think using the DMV's might work.

Answer (score 2):

Even if SQL server agent is not running, you can see how jobs and schedules were set up by viewing the following system DMVs.

```
msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view 
msdb.dbo.sysjobs
msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules
msdb.dbo.sysschedules
```

I use preset scripts to create all my jobs and schedules independent of the server.  Here is a sample script to create the recycle log job.  You can modify this or use any piece of this as you see fit.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS (SELECT job_id 
                FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view 
                WHERE name = N'Cycle SQL log')
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_name=N'Cycle SQL log'
                                , @delete_unused_schedule=1
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_job  
        @job_name = N'Cycle SQL log',
        @description = N'This job forces SQL to start a new error log (In the Managment node of SSMS)',
        @owner_login_name = N'your_sql_login' ;     

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep  
        @job_name = N'Cycle SQL log',  
        @step_name = N'sp_cycle_errorlog', 
        @subsystem = N'TSQL',  
        @command = N'exec sp_cycle_errorlog'  --put your executable code here
  
    --These next two lines set the target server to local, so that the job can be modified if necessary
    SET @sql = 'EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=N''Cycle SQL Log'', @server_name = N''' + @@SERVERNAME + ''''
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @stmt = @sql
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Uh-oh.  Something bad happened when creating the Cycle SQL Log job.  See the following error.'
    PRINT CAST(ERROR_MESSAGE() AS NVARCHAR(1000))
END CATCH
```

You can use use code to automate the addition of schedules based on values you pull from the DMVs listed above.

Comment: This is helpful, but doesn't quite do what I need. I created the same job on both the old and new servers (manually) I'm trying to figure out what the differences are between them, because it didn't work on the new server. But it's a step in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to compare the DMVs on both systems and note any differences?  If not, there could be any number of system configuration differences.